# Is it possible to configure TeamViewer to use a custom port on the LAN?

Tags: teamviewer

We have a remote computer that only has ports 49000 to 49010 available.

We want to control it with TeamViewer.

Is it possible to configure TeamViewer to use LAN only mode, and a custom port other than the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [don't](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/334-Which-ports-are-used-by-TeamViewer.aspx) think that you can change the default port (5938 TCP), but you [can](http://www.teamviewer.com/pl/kb/40-Can-TeamViewer-be-used-within-a-local-network-LAN-only.aspx) use TeamViewer in LAN only mode.